# How would you generate a .txt file

Tags: unix, command, text-files

I have a script that uses "suites" O(n). Basically a linear algorithm to generate possible strings.

It goes like this is to schematize roughtly

```
X = result
x from 1 to x max
y = x max
```

It's chains of possible alphanumeric characters outcomes.

My wish is to transform the script's outcomes (that will generate all possible strings) in one .txt file

Comment: hey there. this is not php code. would you copy and paste the exact php code you are using? for the meantime I removed the php tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you must output what you want from your script. Something like:

```
echo $VARIABLE
```

Then to save the output of the script

```
./yourscript.sh > a.txt
```

To append to a file

```
./yourscript.sh >> a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks ! 

May I venture another question?

I have this array of let's say x columns and y rows where y = x^k 

Can I apply rules in order to generate the array?